# Documentation for camel-package-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I know I shouldn't ask for links on stackoverflow, but after searching in google, duckduckgo, bing and yahoo for documentation of the `camel-package-maven-plugin` I was not able to find even a little bit of documentation about how to use this plugin.
Can anyone tell me where to find a documentation about `camel-package-maven-plugin`? Any non-malware-or-other-type-of-attack-link would be appreciated.

My problem is that I wrote a new camel-component with

- apache camel 2.23.3 and
- spring-boot 2.1.0

the camel-package-maven-plugin writes the following error:

```
[INFO] [WARNING] Missing endpoint documentation for the following options:
[INFO]  encoding
```

And I don't know what and where I am something missing.

Comment: I use Camel for a long time but never heard of camel-package-maven-plugin Can you explain what it does and why do you use it?

Comment: The generated comment says: _generate components meta-data and validate component includes documentation etc_. I got it into my maven project using the `camel-archetype-component` in version `2.22.2`. Due to some changes I switched after using this archetype to camel version `2.23.3`

Comment: As I said I never used that and as you are using Spring Boot you don't need any archetypes: https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

Comment: The archetype only creates the project structure and some template classes with which it is easier (and most times) faster to create the project you want (regarding dependencies and plugins). I am also quite familiar with how to setup a camel project integrating with spring-boot, and it works fine, but when the `camel-package-maven-plugin` says I am missing something in my custom camel component I want to know what I'm missing, and not just remove the plugin ;-) Otherwise the guys from camel wouldn't have made it appear in the recommended archetype for custom components

Comment: You have an option on your endpoint that is not documented, add javadoc to its setter method or add the `@Metadata` annotation to the `@UriParam` where you can document it too.

Comment: @ClausIbsen: Thx that worked and solved my code problem. Still it would be nice if I were able to read some documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no such thing as an official documentation or at least I'm still not able to find it. Anyway, the best documentation is the source code so I go with the source from github: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/tooling/maven/camel-package-maven-plugin

Comment: Just came across a reference to this plugin on the [Type Converter](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/type-converter.html#TypeConverter-HowTypeConversionworks) documentation. I'm also curious about how this plugin works and similarly couldn't find any documentation.